# How to draw this matrix

Tags: matrices

Do you have any idea how to draw the attached matrix?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try with `nicematrix` package. What you try so far?

Comment: what is the font used to typeset `a` in the matrix  -- the `subscripts` are slightly lower -- the `d` in the subscript is upright and not `slanted` as normal

Answer (score 4):

Here is a proposition with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    xdots = 
     {
       color = gray ,
       shorten = 3pt ,
       horizontal-labels  % with nicematrix ≥ 6.20 
     }
  }

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[columns-width=8mm,first-row,first-col]
& \Hdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},color=black]{4}^{d_u} \\
\Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},color=black]{4}_{d_1}
& a_{11} & a_{12} & \Cdots & a_{1d_u} & 0 & \Cdots & & 0 \\[1.5mm]
& a_{21} & a_{22} &  &         &   & &   & \Vdots \\[1.5mm]
& \Vdots &  & \Ddots &        &    & \Ddots  &  \Ddots &   \\[1.5mm]
& a_{d_11}&  &    &        &    &   &   & 0 \\[1.5mm]
& 0      &  \Ddots[shorten-end=-5mm] &    &        &    &   &   & a_{n-d_u+1,n}  \\[1.5mm]
& \Vdots & \Ddots &    &        &    &   &   &   \\[1.5mm]
&       &  &    &        &    &   &   &  \Vdots \\[1.5mm]
& 0  & \Cdots &    & 0 & a_{n,n-d_1+1}   & \Cdots  &   &  a_{nn}\\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Excuse me very much if sometimes I done some comments: why the long dots from ad_11 are broken before a_n,n-d_1+1?

Comment: `nicematrix` parallelizes the diagonal dotted lines: the first `\Ddots` draws its line and the other lines are constructed parallel to the first one. In this aim, the lower right extremity of the dotted line is vertically translated as to have a line parallel to the first diagonal line. The result is not perfect... in particular when the elements have very different widths. It's also possible to disable parallelization with a key but, usually, the result seems strange...

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and exhaustive explanation.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I have adjusted the length of the problematic dotted line "by hand", that is to say with the key `shorten-end` of `\Ddots`...

Comment: Thank you very much for your adivce.